# Trouble writing a dummy variable for a range of numbers in r

Tags: r

I am having issues trying to set this up. I am trying write a dummy variable where A23 = 1 if X27 > 70 and A23 = 0 if X27 ≤ 70.

I have tried a bunch of different things and I think I am just misunderstanding how r is reading the == of the equations. Any help would be great

Code

```r
dataframe$A23 = ifelse(dataframe$X23== X23<=70,1,0)
```

packages: mosaic & broom

Comment: you might benefit from this: https://www.listendata.com/2017/03/if-else-in-r.html

hint: your test (first part of the `ifelse())` is off.

Comment: Thank you @D.J this should be a great resource (I wish I found it sooner)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues will arise often at the beginning of programming. Whenever that is the case, type `?Name_of_function()` in your R console and read a bit about the function you are using and then scroll down to the very end of the help file and see the examples. Try to understand those examples, or copy and adapt to your case. This will solve most of your problems. And whenever there is an error, dont panic, read carefully the messages. They usually tell you a lot about what went wrong.

```r
# A23 = 1 if X27 > 70 and A23 = 0 if X27 ≤ 70.
dataframe$A23 = ifelse(dataframe$X23>70,1,0)
dataframe
#>        X23 A23
#> 1 69.43952   0
#> 2 69.76982   0
#> 3 71.55871   1
#> 4 70.07051   1
#> 5 70.12929   1
```

### data

```r
set.seed(123)
dataframe <- data.frame(
  X23 = rnorm(5, 70)
)
```